# Compile-time integrity verification of versioned struct

Tags: c++, c++11, struct

I have a struct called FOO that's versioned, so we have `FOO_V0`, `FOO_V1`, and `FOO_V2`. This is legacy architecture so I am currently not at a liberty to change it. However, I wanted to see if I could insert some compile-time checks such as `static_assert` that make sure `FOO_V0 + d` is `F00_V1` and `FOO_V1 + e` is `FOO_V2` so the integrity is somewhat enforced. Is that possible? TIA for any feedback!

```
typedef struct FOO_V0
{
    UINT a;   
    BOOL b;
    LARGE_INTEGER c;
} FOO_V0;

typedef struct FOO_V1
{
    UINT a;   
    BOOL b;
    LARGE_INTEGER c;
    UINT d;
} FOO_V1;

typedef struct FOO_V2
{
    UINT a;   
    BOOL b;
    LARGE_INTEGER c;
    UINT d;
    BOOL e;
} FOO_V2;
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "`FOO_V0 + d` is `F00_V1` and `FOO_V1 + e` is `FOO_V2`"?

Comment: Do you want to check that each new version only adds member at the end of the struct, to know if it is safe to slice a `V2` in a `V1`?

Comment: Where do you want to put your assertions if you cannot modify the code of `FOO_V*`?

Comment: We are working on adding FOO_V2 now, and I wanted to have some checks to make sure someone wouldn't do something silly like swapping `a` and `d` around.